# Converting string to Integer, not using int.parse or tryParse in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I've this code.

```
string str = "789654";

static int Parser(string str)
{

   int result = 0;

   foreach (var item in str)
   {
      result = result * 10;
      result = result + item - '0';
   }
}
```

I am trying to figure out why I've to append - '0' at last to the result. I know if I don't then it will take ASCII characters in the result like for example for 7

-- It will print out 55 in the result for number 7.

Comment: Basically the Ascii character values for 0-9 are sequential, so subtracting the Ascii value for the character 0 will give the integer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `item` in your `str` is not `int`, but it's `char`.

In [ascii-code table](https://www.ascii-code.com/), '0' is not 0, but it's 48, which means `'0' == 48` when casted to int.

As you are already aware of it, if you want a number which is represented in character to act as an real `int`, you have to substract it's ascii-code value.

For example, `'1' == 49`, `'0' == 48`. So `'1' - '0' == 49 - 48 == 1`.